# Plasmati Graduate CV - Total number of pages

Tags: cv

I am using [Plasmati Graduate CV Latex Template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/plasmati-graduate-cv), and I want to add the total number of pages to be like:

```
Page Number / Total Number of Pages
```

Comment: You can do that with the `lastpage` or `totpage` package.

Comment: Total number of pages in some class of latex document counts easily - give `\label{smth}` at the end before `\end{document}` Then use `\pageref{smth}~pages`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was done using `fanchyhdr` and `lastpage`

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\thepage \hspace{1pt} / \pageref*{LastPage}}
```